# Dropping 2 pins with long tap

Tags: iphone, mapping, gesture-recognition

I'm detecting a long tap to put a pin on the map and its working, I add a pinId variable that i increment evry time i drop a poin to check that only two pins are dropped in the same map but here something is not working fine i guess because i can only put one pin on the map!

Here is the code:

```
-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

{

  [self.mapView removeGestureRecognizer:sender];

}else{ 
    if (pinId < 3) {


        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];


        MapAppAnnotation* annotation = [[MapAppAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:locCoord andID:pinId];
        pinId++;
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        [annotation release];

    }}
}

- (void)update{


UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];

[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];


[longPressGesture release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
//...

pinId = 1;

 self.update;
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure your else part is called the second time you perform long press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess; it's because `removeGestureRecognizer` is being called after the first long press. Does it work if you remove that call?